# Why doesn't this select statement, setting a variable, work?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am writing a stored procedure like this..

```
declare @avg float
set @avg = select avg(rating) from videorating where videoid = 4
```

Can I write it like this? Can I store the value in @avg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write it

```
declare @avg float
select @avg=avg(rating) from videorating where videoid = 4
```

Comment: (Which is bloody amazing...you're like the king of SQL. And fast.)

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: Quassnoi's faster - even his wife says so ;) :D